# Client app registration for Retail server authentication on AX RTW?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7

We are facing challenge in Retail server authentication for Customer(C2 authentication) through .Net Web API.

following this on AX community, but didn't had any luck till now

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/205387

Any help is highly appreciated, we are kind of blocked here.......

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution for this.

After following all the steps, you just need to restart the Retail server from IIS to update accepted audiences(Relying parties).